# Using require.js with 3rd party javascript libraries

Tags: requirejs

I'm just starting to use `require.js` and think it's great.  However, I would like to use it as much as possible instead of dealing with `<script>` tags in my HTML files.

To that end, is it possible to work with a 3rd party library that doesn't have any `define` modules in it?  This may be asking much I realize but is there a way to call...

```
require(["3rd_party"], function(3rd) {
```

});

...where `3rd_party.js` is a script located in a js folder that require knows to look in?  I know require has mapping libraries, things like `require-jquery` but wasn't sure if it's possible to use it out of the box with older utility libraries that weren't built with it in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RequireJS` 2.1.0 added the `shim` config element which allows using non-AMD 3rd party libraries like AMD modules.
In your case it would be something like:

```js
shim: {
    '3rd_party': {
        exports: '{the-global-name}' // what variable does the library
                                     // export to the global scope?
    }
}
```

This mechanism makes custom-build library wrappers like "require-jquery" pretty much obsolete.

More details in the [RequireJS docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)