# How to include 3rd party scripts with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, frontend, amd

I'm trying out AMD-way of handling scipts and my choise fell upon requirejs. In this project I use MDL (front-end framework; for those who haven't heard of it think of it as bootstrap 3) which should be included as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.min.css">
<script src="/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

I am not interested in js API that this framework is providing (if it provides any), I need this script only for UI to work properly when I attach framwerk-specific classes to elements.

According to requirejs philosophy I need only one script file to be included with a `script` tag on my page - the entry point. I understand that in that main script I need to require dependencies. And if it was say jQuery or underscore i.e. the library I actually **require** and my code depends on, I would write something like:

```
require(
    ['jquery'],
     function($) {
        $('body').append(...);
    }
);
```

But how do I roll if it's not an actual dependency but I still need it to be loaded in my page and, in this particular case, I need it to be loaded first.

What do I do? My guess is I remove the `script` tag from my `head` and specify it in square brackets in my entry point script (as I did for jquery in snippet above) but just don't use it. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592308/using-require-js-with-3rd-party-javascript-libraries

Comment: @brandelizer thank you but the link you gave adresses different problem.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I roll if it's not an actual dependency but I still need it to be loaded in my page and, in this particular case, I need it to be loaded first.

RequireJS only guarantees the relative order in which modules are loaded. If a module must absolutely be loaded first, then the chain of dependencies must be such that everything else depends on it, directly or indirectly. RequireJS does not provide a method to say "load this before everything else". You can get this effect only through dependencies. (Sometimes people think the `deps` configuration option guarantees that some modules will load first. It does not. Or they think that the order of dependencies in a `require` or `define` call sets an order for loading *beyond* what the dependencies set. It does not. If `A` and `B` have no dependencies of their own then `require(['A', 'B'], ...` and `require['B', 'A'], ...` are both free to load the modules in any order.)

> What do I do? My guess is I remove the script tag from my head and specify it in square brackets in my entry point script (as I did for jquery in snippet above) but just don't use it. Is it correct?

In theory there's no problem with doing this. I say "in theory" because I do not use MDL so I don't know if MDL has any need that would prevent it from working. You've compared MDL with Bootstrap 3. What you describe is how I load Bootstrap with RequireJS. I tend to use the CommonJS idiom so modules that need Bootstrap look something like this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
'use strict';

require("bootstrap");
```

There's no need to do something like `var bootstrap = require("bootstrap");` because the value would be `undefined` anyway because the JS code of Bootstrap installs itself as jQuery plugins.